# Antislash extra double quotes with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, regex

I've got an incorrect JSON inside of a string that I want to parse. What's make it incorrect is that there are double quotes characters inside of it.

---

**INCORRECT JSON**

`{ "key": "the log that is broken use the character " which brake the json", "key2": "value2" }`

---

**CORRECT JSON**

`{ "key": "the log that is broken use the character \" which brake the json", "key2": "value2" }`

---

Is there any regex I could use with `replace` in order to backlash the extra `"` so I could parse the JSON ?

```js
const json = `{ "key": "the log that is broken use the character " which brake the json", "key2": "value2" }`;

// Do the regex and the replace ...

const obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj);
```

I have tried multiple regex of my own but couldn't make it work. Also if you just got lead I'll try them out myself.

Thank you

---

---

EDIT :

Here is a working soluce I've coded. Bit much If you ask me, I would appreciate a better soluce :

```js
const json = `{ "key": "the log that is broken use the character " which brake the json", "key2": "value2" }`;

console.log(json);

// Get all occurences of the troubled strings
const [
  _,
  ...results
] = /(?:\: "(?:(.*)*)",)|(?:\: "(?:(.*)*)" )/.exec(json);

let mutatedJson = json;

// For each occurence, replace the extra double quotes, then apply it on the main string
results.slice(0, results.length - 1).forEach((x) => {
   const oldVal = x;
   
   // Take the string without the first and last double quotes and backslash remaining quotes
   const newVal = x.replace('"', "\\\"");
   
   // Insert the clean data in
   mutatedJson = mutatedJson.replace(oldVal, newVal);
});

const obj = JSON.parse(mutatedJson);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: It depends a lot on what you know about this JSON structure. Do you know with certainty which keys contain the error? Do you know if they can also contain a comma (otherwise you could use it as a delimiter). Because with no prior knowledge, there's very little chance of parsing a generic JSON-like structure with a regex.

Comment: Yes I know the keys and the structure. I know that the only problem inside of the JSON is that there are extra double quotes in the value behind the key X.

Comment: Out curiosity... Is the broken JSON generated by this same app? Because it might be easier and more reliable to fix that instead.

Comment: What Alvaro said is what I was thinking. Plus you may encounter many other characters which might cause problem. Fixing it at the source is the best way to go.

Comment: The broken JSON was generated in a app a while ago, and now we have to treat the data... PS: We have To of data. Classic real life work issue ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what you could do.

```js
var json = `{ "key": "the log that is broken use " the character " which brake the json", "key2": "value2" }`;

var problemKey = "key";

var problemStart = json.indexOf(problemKey) + problemKey.length + 1;
var valueStart = json.indexOf("\"", problemStart) + 1;
var valueEnd = json.indexOf(",", problemStart);
var value = json.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);
valueEnd = json.lastIndexOf("\"", valueEnd);
console.log(json.substring(valueStart, valueEnd));
value = json.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);

json = json.substring(0, valueStart)
 + json.substring(valueStart, valueEnd).replace(/"/g, "\\\"")
 + json.substring(valueEnd);
  
console.log(json);

const obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj);
```

The (strong) assumptions here are two

1. you know the problematic key,
2. the values do not contain a comma.

If your values can contain a comma, then you could maybe find the end of the problematic value by looking for the next key, assuming again that you are certain of what that is.

As others have said in the comments, of course, the better approach would certainly be to fix the JSON at the source.

Comment: Thank you, I guess there are no other way than doing extra stuff along with regex